# Class extension strange index syntax.

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I found the following code in one of my favourite AI libraries (Encog by Jeff Heaton et al).

The code seems to have some sort of extension on the class that I am assuming allows it to be accessed as a double value.

```
public interface IMLDataModifiable: IMLData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The index to access.</param>
    new double this[int x] { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what this sort of extension is called so that I can look into it in greater detail?

I will need to replicate this in my own C++ Cli library. An answer to this question would help by giving me a great starting point for further research.

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: This may well be a duplicate however I was unaware of the terminology to describe this syntax so I was unable to look. Thank you for @Yuval Itzchakov for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me what this sort of extension is called so that I can
>   look into it in greater detail?

This is called an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). It lets you access the object at a specified index given an `int` value, returning a `double`.

For example, given this very naive implementation, say we have a backing store of doubles in our class and we want to expose `Foo` via an indexer, we can do:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<double> doubles = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

    public double this[int x]
    {
        get { return doubles[x]; }
        set { doubles[x] = value; }
    }
}
```

And then access our `Foo` object using this indexer:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(foo[1]);
}
```

Will yield 2.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign You welcome.